# CreateProcess not in primary thread

Tags: c++, interprocess

I use CreateProcess() to start a other programm from my C++ code. 
The [helppage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that it

> Creates a new process and its primary thread. The new process runs in the security context of the calling process.

I would like to have it in his own thread, so the application would keep on going. Is there any simple way to do so? I am not familar with boost and Co.

My code:

```
bool startup(LPWSTR lpApplicationName)
{
   STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        lpApplicationName,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return false;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    return true;
}
```

and how to call the function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
wchar_t path[] = L"C:\\path\\to\\paridise.exe";
startup(path);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem ? Here you use `CreateProcess`, then wait for it to finish with `WaitForSingleObject`. Just remove the wait and it will not wait.

Comment: awww, moments when it's time to stop working and go home :D Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

*Transforming the comment by ElderBug in a reply*

The problem in your code is the presence of an infinite wait after the `CreateProcess` call:

> WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

Just comment it and the program execution will not stop.

I also did this same error and I stumbled in this SO question; the fact is that many of us get the code from the MSDN example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes) (without much attention), which has in fact this infinite wait.